# Unable to update service reference in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: web-services, visual-studio, reference

I am unable to update the service reference has recently been updated. The service appears within a folder.
Is the only option to delete and re-add...?
I tried exclude from project.
Don't ask me why all the services are under folders because I don't know!!

[image: vs-2013]

Comment: Looks like this is a problem cause by TFS. Still investigating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By editing the .vbproj file, folders revert to appearing as web services.
Find the section which looks like this and add an item for each service:

```
      <ItemGroup>
    <WCFMetadataStorage Include="Service References\DocsSrvGdTracker\" />
    <WCFMetadataStorage Include="Service References\DBForms\" />
    <WCFMetadataStorage Include="Service References\JSONtest\" />
    <WCFMetadataStorage Include="Service References\CalServ\" />
    <WCFMetadataStorage Include="Service References\England_Address\" />
    <WCFMetadataStorage Include="Service References\NI_Address\" />
    <WCFMetadataStorage Include="Service References\PhotoService\" />
    <WCFMetadataStorage Include="Service References\RdSAP\" />
    <WCFMetadataStorage Include="Service References\ReportServices\" />
    <WCFMetadataStorage Include="Service References\Scotland_Address\" />
    <WCFMetadataStorage Include="Service References\XMLDownload\" />
    <WCFMetadataStorage Include="Service References\XMLService\" />
  </ItemGroup>
```